# Are @font-face fonts loaded by browser even if not used?

Tags: css, font-face

So I have this stack:

```
 @font-face {
    font-family: 'MyCustomFont';
    src: url('MyCustomFont.ttf') format('truetype');
 }

 body { font-family: Helvetica, MyCustomFont, Arial, sans-serif; }
```

Is `MyCustomFont.tff` loaded by browser even if Helvetica is present in the machine (ie: Mac Users)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `local` directive to test for the locally installed version of the font.  If it is not found, the next font in the list will be tested for, and loaded if available.  For example:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: MyHelvetica;
    src: local("Helvetica Neue Bold"),
    local("HelveticaNeue-Bold"),
    url(MgOpenModernaBold.ttf);
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

The above example was taken from here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/@font-face

There's some more information here:
http://www.broken-links.com/2009/06/30/checking-for-installed-fonts-with-font-face-and-local/

Once a font has been downloaded, it will be cached by the browser.  Once in the cache, it will not be necessary for the browser to download the font again, thereby speeding things up.  See here for more information:
http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/faq.html#Performance

Comment: @achairapart: I agree. The use of web fonts is a step in the right direction (moving away from image replacements), but it is by no means perfect. I have many variants of Helvetica installed on my computer, but there's no guarantee that I'll have the one you're testing for. For now at least, I think you have to either take the performance hit of downloading web fonts, settle for the few reasonably standard 'web safe' fonts, or just cross your fingers and hope for the best ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Jake Archibald gave a very good talk about this in the Dibi 2011.

You can see here: http://vimeo.com/27771157 min. 11:59

And here: http://speakerdeck.com/u/jaffathecake/p/in-your-font-face?slide=39